# Subtracting 1 from int acting very strange

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this seems like a really dumb question. But all im trying to do is subtract `1` from my int.

```
    int *subtractor = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"numberOfAlerts"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i", subtractor);
    subtractor--;
    NSLog(@"%d", subtractor);
    NSNumber *savedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:subtractor];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:savedNumber forKey:@"numberOfAlerts"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

The console prints out :

`1`
`-3`

when it loads the info from defaults, its `1` which is good. 
Then i try to subtract 1 to make it 0, but it goes to -3. This is so frustrating! ANy help is greatly appreciated!

**For the Record**

i change the code to 
    subtractor++;
and it should have printed out `1` `2`.

But it printed out `1` `5`. So it added four.

Comment: What you are doing in your code is **pointer arithmetic**. I am not sure if that is your intention or not, http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: @MikeD no its not my intention. I just wanted to subtract the value of the int. not the pointer. However David Buck's answer is giving me a `sigabrt` error. Do you know why? Thank you for the help!

Comment: The code block you have looks OK. The only thing I can think of is the first NSLog, try @"%d", %i is not in specifier list. But I would be surprised if that were the case. Unfortunately, I am not near a Mac right now, so I can't run your code to verify.

Comment: Please, please, please learn a smidgen of C before you attempt Objective-C!!!!

Comment: @HotLicks i already have an app on the store using core data, and other difficult elements of ios dev and objective-c. I am sorry i dont know every aspect of the base language

Comment: Knowledge of pointers is not "every aspect" of C -- it's very fundamental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intValue` returns an int, not a pointer to int.

You have to declare subtractor as an int:

```
 int subtractor = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"numberOfAlerts"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtractor is a pointer to an int and the code is decrementing the pointer, not the int.  Try `(*subtractor)--`

Comment: Or `int sub = [[[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"numberOfAlerts"] intValue]`

Comment: @DavidBuck that makes total sense. But when i try to subtract using (*subtractor)--; it crashes and gives me a `sigabrt` error! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found the problem. I was being a total N00B and i was using a pointer to create the int. 

int*subtractor...; 

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: The problem is not the pointer arithmetic, the problem is assigning the return value of `intValue` to an int pointer.